# Dnsmasq: Redirect entire domain to localhost only for specific MAC Addresses

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I'd like to redirect example.com to the local host, but only for specific MAC addresses.
Obviously, specifying

```
address=/example.com/127.0.0.1
```

in dnsmasq.conf does this for everyone. Is there any way that say MAC1 will be redirected to localhost, while MAC2 will get the correct IP address of example.com?

Comment: The MAC address is only relevant between the hardware and the kernel. The standard socket APIs never even see it. Any decisions you want to make based on MAC address have to happen in kernel space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  no.  Dnsmasq does not have that kind of functionality.  The `--address` setting applies globally.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Linux you could use iptables to redirect traffic to different DNS servers based on their MAC addresses.